# Copiar dados de uma coluna (B), para outra planilha, caso condiçao da coluna (F) seja atendida. excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Tentei e continuo tentando diversos códigos para automatizar a cópia de dados (coluna B, planilha proposals) para outra outra planilha (projects), tambem na coluna B, caso a coluna F da planilha "proposals" contenha os termos "Aceita" ou "Enviada".

Ambas planilhas estao com a mesma formataçao. Cabeçalho da tabela em B3:J3 e início de dados em B4:Jx

Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Edite a pergunta e apresente o que já tentou elaborar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar o seguinte código, que verifica o conteúdo da coluna F da planilha "proposals" e caso seja igual a "Aceita" ou "Enviada", copia o valor da coluna B da planilha "proposals" para a coluna B da planilha "projects". Esse código para de ser executado quando o valor da coluna B da planilha "proposals" estiver em branco.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

i = 4
j = 4

While (Worksheets("proposals").Cells(i, 2) <> "")
    If (Worksheets("proposals").Cells(i, 6) = "Aceita" Or Worksheets("proposals").Cells(i, 6) = "Enviada") Then
        Worksheets("projects").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("proposals").Cells(i, 2)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: FWIW: Tente declarar estas variáveis como `Long` e não `Integer`. Pois com Integer a Planilha trava ao passar da linha 32767.

Comment: Você tem rezão. Eu havia declarado como `Integer` imaginando uma planilha com poucas linhas. Editei a resposta, alterando para `Long`.